# How does Laravel find and display the dynamic attributes on Eloquent models when using the tinker CLI?

Tags: php, laravel, formatting, laravel-artisan, tinker

When we use `artisan tinker`, and reference an Eloquent model object, the REPL automatically prints the model's attributes, much like how it prints the public properties of any standard object we reference:

```
>>> (object) ['hello' => 'world']
 => {
      +"hello": "world",
    }

>>> App\User::first()
 => App\User {
      id: 1,
      name: "...",
   }
```

What's less obvious to me is *how* these virtual attributes can be made to appear here, as if they were already defined as public properties of the class. I understand that much of the attribute assignment for the model is handled internally by the `HasAttributes` trait, but even looking there, I still don't see how the Laravel authors were able to achieve this behavior.

I've tried building a class like this:

```
class Bunch implements Arrayable, ArrayAccess, Jsonable, JsonSerializable { ... }
```

but even with working array access and a `toArray` method, when I reference it directly from `artisan tinker`:

```
>>> $b = new Bunch()
 => Bunch {}
>>> $b->one = 1
 => 1
>>> $b['one']
 => 1
>>> $b
 => Bunch {}
```

How can we change the representation that the REPL uses when it prints an object like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code that determines how to display the attributes of a model in Tinker is in the Tinker code, not in the model:

- https://github.com/laravel/tinker/blob/2.x/src/TinkerCaster.php

Casters are part of the [Symfony VarDumper component](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/var_dumper/advanced.html) which is used by [PsySH](https://github.com/bobthecow/psysh) to display classes.  Tinker is built on top of PsySH.

Tinker maps the casters to the classes in its Console command class:

- https://github.com/laravel/tinker/blob/2.x/src/Console/TinkerCommand.php

This returns the mapping of the classes to their casters:

```
/**
     * Get an array of Laravel tailored casters.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected function getCasters()
    {
        $casters = [
            'Illuminate\Support\Collection' => 'Laravel\Tinker\TinkerCaster::castCollection',
            'Illuminate\Support\HtmlString' => 'Laravel\Tinker\TinkerCaster::castHtmlString',
            'Illuminate\Support\Stringable' => 'Laravel\Tinker\TinkerCaster::castStringable',
        ];

        if (class_exists('Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model')) {
            $casters['Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model'] = 'Laravel\Tinker\TinkerCaster::castModel';
        }

        if (class_exists('Illuminate\Foundation\Application')) {
            $casters['Illuminate\Foundation\Application'] = 'Laravel\Tinker\TinkerCaster::castApplication';
        }

        return $casters;
    }
```

This sets the casters on the VarDumper:

```
        $config->getPresenter()->addCasters(
            $this->getCasters()
        );
```

If you want to add additional properties from the model to be displayed in Tinker, you can use the $[appends](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-serialization#appending-values-to-json) property on the model:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
    /**
     * The accessors to append to the model's array form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $appends = ['is_admin'];
}
```

Comment: Yes! This is totally what I was looking for. Adding `$casters['App\Bunch'] = 'App\Bunch::castBunch';` allows me to define a custom method to handle the REPL representation of my custom class. Thank you so much!

Answer (score -1):

Eloquent automatically fills Model attributes using the Database connection set up.